# JPQL JPA - Criar uma lista agrupada por data com o somatório e o lucro de todos os itens vendidos naquele dia

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data, jpql

A consulta SQL abaixo esta retornando um resultado errado para o campo valorEntrega.

```
SELECT
DATE(p.dt_pedido) AS  barChartLabels,
COUNT( DISTINCT p.id) AS qtdPedido,
SUM((item.quantidade * item.preco) * p.taxa_compra) AS percentualCompra,
SUM(item.quantidade * item.preco) AS valoresTotal,
SUM(p.taxa_bairro) AS valorEntregaAS valorEntrega

FROM pedido p, item_pedido item
where (p.id = item.pedido_id)
GROUP BY DATE(p.dt_pedido)
```

Ao invés dele simplesmente realizar a somatória do valor do Pedido.taxa_Bairro, ele esta multiplicando este pedido.taxa_Bairro pela quantidade de itens de cada pedido e depois somando estes resultados. Como fazer para que ele somente realize a somatória e não a multiplicação? Abaixo o diagrama:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A idéia é que após a correção do SQL eu consiga converter-la para JPQL. Grato

Comment: Estive observando que mesmo apesar de não estar escrito na query, ela esta pegando o valor da taxaBairro do Pedido e multiplicando pela quantidade de itens que tem neste pedido, e o correto é não ocorrer esta multiplicação. Esta multiplicação não pode ocorrer, como fazer isso?

Comment: Tente não colocar imagens de códigos, ao invés disso cole o código no corpo da pergunta mesmo, como no caso do JSON e do código SQL, fica mais fácil para quem for ler sua pergunta e tentar responde-la. No caso das imagens de tela tudo bem.

Comment: Você está usando MySQL? Por que está usando `DISTINCT` para retornar a data do pedido e o count do id? Não seria necessário para a data, se você já está agrupando por ela, e para o id também é desncessário, porque o id deveria ser único. Qual o retorno de `SUM(p.taxa_bairro)` se colocar só ele no `SELECT`?

Comment: Eu sugiro que você dê uma lida nesse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No seu caso, creio que só bastava postar a sua consulta SQL, porque é lá que está o problema e é lá que você quer ajuda. Quando você posta um texto muito grande assim, muito cheio de detalhes, pode ser que menos pessoas leiam ele por completo, então, se não for necessário, o melhor é tentar colocar o menos possível, o suficiente para identificar o problema.

Comment: Obrigado @PedroGaspar, vou editar a pergunta observando o artigo que vc colocou.

Comment: @PedroGaspar, se eu deixo somente SUM(p.taxa_Bairro) e retiro todos os demais campos do SQL, além de retirar a ligação com a outra tabela ele realiza o calculo corretamente, porém se insiro a ligação com a tabela filha, seja desta forma ou join, ele volta a multiplicar pelas linhas dos itens antes de somar.

Comment: Mas a ligação com a outra tabela está no `WHERE` e não na lista de campos selecionados!

Comment: @PedroGaspar, o que esta acontecendo é que por causa da ligação ele esta repetindo o pedido.taxa_Bairro pelo mesmo numero da quantidade de itens e depois somando. É como se antes do SUM ele replicasse a linha 14 (numero de itens) vezes. (Estou utilizando MySQL)

Comment: Sugiro que acrescente no texto da pergunta detalhes sobre as colunas das tabelas. Por exemplo, o que contém `p.taxa_compra`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de conversar com o autor através dos comentários, percebi que o problema acontecia porque ao fazer uma consulta com *full join* ([Retrieving Records from Multiple Tables | MySQL SQL Syntax and Use | InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5)), o número de registros percorridos era o número de registros da tabela `item_pedido` (14 registros).

No exemplo dele o retorno da tabela `pedido`, para pedidos feitos na data 01/11/2018, trazia 2 registros:

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id  |      dt_pedido      | taxa_bairro | taxa_compra |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 227 | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |
| 228 | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

E o retorno da tabela `item_pedido`, para os itens relacionados àqueles 2 pedidos, trazia 14 registros:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| pedido_id | preco | quantidade |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       227 | 35.00 |       1.00 |
|       227 | 25.21 |       1.00 |
|       227 | 16.10 |       1.00 |
|       227 | 23.10 |       3.00 |
|       227 |  2.00 |       2.00 |
|       227 |  6.00 |       2.00 |
|       227 |  1.00 |       2.00 |
|       227 | 33.55 |       2.00 |
|       227 | 21.22 |       1.00 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       228 | 20.12 |       2.00 |
|       228 | 11.10 |       2.00 |
|       228 | 21.22 |       2.00 |
|       228 | 13.22 |       1.00 |
|       228 | 25.21 |       3.00 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Então, após o *full join* das duas tabelas:

```sql
FROM pedido p, item_pedido item
WHERE p.id = item.pedido_id
```

O retorno seria uma junção dos dois resultados, ou seja, 14 registros:

```
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------+
|  id   |      dt_pedido      | taxa_bairro | taxa_compra | pedido_id | preco | quantidade |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------+
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 35.00 |       1.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 25.21 |       1.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 16.10 |       1.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 23.10 |       3.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 |  2.00 |       2.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 |  6.00 |       2.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 |  1.00 |       2.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 33.55 |       2.00 |
| 227   | 2018-11-01 03:26:19 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       227 | 21.22 |       1.00 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------+
| 228   | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       228 | 20.12 |       2.00 |
| 228   | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       228 | 11.10 |       2.00 |
| 228   | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       228 | 21.22 |       2.00 |
| 228   | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       228 | 13.22 |       1.00 |
| 228   | 2018-11-01 03:39:09 |        1.00 |        0.10 |       228 | 25.21 |       3.00 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Por isso o retorno do campo `SUM(p.taxa_bairro)` era '14.00', ao invés do valor '2.00' esperado pelo autor.

Para resolver isso, pode-se colocar a somatória dos valores dos itens do pedido em uma *subquery*, dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(p.dt_pedido) AS barChartLabels,
  COUNT(p.id) AS qtdPedido,
  SUM(itens.valorTotalPedido * p.taxa_compra) AS percentualCompra,
  itens.valorTotalPedido AS valoresTotal,
  (SUM(itens.valorTotalPedido * p.taxa_compra) + SUM(p.taxa_bairro)) AS valorEntrega
FROM pedido AS p
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT pedido_id, SUM(quantidade * preco) AS valorTotalPedido
      FROM item_pedido
      GROUP BY pedido_id
     ) AS itens
   ON itens.pedido_id = p.id
GROUP BY DATE(p.dt_pedido)
```

Confira o resultado no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af8db5/14/0).

Comment: Ola Pedro, o problema que relatei realmente é este, descrito por vc. Porém o código esta dando um erro "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause" , já tentei alterando o alias 'p' para o nome da tabela, porém o erro continua. Estou utilizando o MySQL.

Comment: @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto, alterei para `FROM pedido p INNER JOIN (SELECT  ...`, veja se agora funciona.

Comment: Não Pedro, continua a mesma falha, também estou tentando por aqui. Sua linha de raciocínio esta perfeita, só tenho que identificar o que na sintaxe devo adequar.

Comment: Fiz uma nova edição na resposta, veja se agora ficou OK.

Comment: @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto, agora está funcionando, coloquei inclusive um link para o SQL Fiddle, dê uma olhada e diga se ficou OK aí para você também.

Comment: Pedro, estudando seu código consegui fazer rodar, segue o código atualizado para vc colocar na resposta.  select 
DATE(pedido.dt_pedido ) AS barChartLabels ,
COUNT(pedido.id) AS qtdPedido,
SUM(itens.total * pedido.taxa_compra) as percentualCompra,
SUM(pedido.taxa_bairro) AS valorEntrega,
SUM(itens.total) as custoProdutos
from pedido
inner join 
( select pedido_id as pedido_id, SUM(item.quantidade * item.preco) as total
  from item_pedido item group by item.pedido_id ) as itens on itens.pedido_id = pedido.id
group by  DATE(pedido.dt_pedido )

Comment: Obrigado o apoio.